# Take sum of two editText's and put it in textView

Tags: android, button, textview, android-edittext

I have been looking everywhere but i can't find the answer, i'm just a beginner, thanks in advance for all answers.

I want to put two editText's in activity_main.xml and when the app is open on the phone the user can write some numbers in those two editTexts and then click on Button, and the sum of these two editTexts to output in textView.

Answer (score 0):

try this on button submit.

```
 `btnSubmit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(validation()){
            int result = Integer.parseInt(edObjOne.getText().toString().trim())+ 
              Integer.parseInt(edObjTwo.getText().toString().trim());
            textViewObj.setText(String.valueOf(result));
                }
        }
    });`

        private boolean validation() {

            if (edObjOne.getText().toString().trim().equals("")) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Field one empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return false;
            }

            if (edObjTwo.getText().toString().trim().equals("")) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Field two empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return false;
            }

            return true;
    }
```

set edittext property number & android:digits="1234567890" in xml layout.
                                    .